# Объекты Javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот список объектов Javascript.

> `anchor (массив anchors)   
> location
> button
> Math
> checkbox
> navigator
> Date    
> password
> document    
> radio
> массив elements 
> reset
> form (массив forms) 
> string
> frame (массив frames)   
> submit
> hidden  
> text
> history 
> textarea
> link (массив links) 
> window`

Верно ли, что все из перечисленного является объектами Javascript и что других объектов нет? Если знаете другие объекты, пожалуйста, пишите в ответе.

Comment: Объектов, @Семен, может быть бесчисленное множество! Любая функция, форма, ... ... - это объекты в JavaScript.

Comment: В JavaScript абсолютно все - объект. По сабжу - конечно не верно, их еще туева туча.

Comment: `null` и `undefined` не объекты, строки, числа и true/false не объекты, но имеют соответсвующие объектные обёртки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начитывайтесь [Объекты JavaScript](http://freehost.com.ua/faq/buleten/article/article_id/16)

Comment: @Palmervan и это тоже далеко не все.

Comment: Понятно что не все, но хорошо описано!

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {};//объект

var b = [1,2,3];//тоже объект

var c = new Date();//да что ж такое, тоже объект

var d = function(){return true;};//и это объект
```

Чак Норрис может продолжить этот список до бесконечности

Comment: Хотя именно в языке, если отбросить браузерную реализацию, их не намного больше